# Agregar texto encima de una imagen al hacer hover

Tags: html, css, css3

Llevo todo el día intentando adaptar mi código para que cuando haga hover en una imagen salga un texto cuando termine el efecto de opacidad, pero no encuentro la manera, alguno sabría como puedo hacerlo??? este es el trozo de código que quiero modificar:

```css
.image {
    float: left; 
    width: 28%; 
    margin: 10px
}

.image iframe{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

.desvanecer:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"> 
  <img class="desvanecer" src="img/teamfight-tactics-little-legends-1- 
             900x506.jpg">
  <iframe src="https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/es/" frameborder="0"> 
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que salga un texto cuando termine el efecto de opacidad? ¿Y dónde tendría que aparecer el texto (encima, debajo, a la derecha, sobre la imagen, etc...)?

Comment: El texto debería estar sobre la imagen, es decir que cuando pase el ratón por encima de la imagen, se haga el efecto de opacidad y salga un texto

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres sacar un texto a la vez que el efecto de opacidad (según entiendo de los comentarios) creo que lo más sencillo es ponerle el atributo `title` a la imagen en el HTML.

```
<img class="desvanecer" src="url..." title="Texto encima">
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
.image {
    float: left;
    width: 28%; 
    margin: 10px
}

.image iframe{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

.desvanecer{
  max-width: 300px;
}

.desvanecer:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"> 
     <img class="desvanecer" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" title="Texto encima">
     <iframe src="https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/es/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Este podria ser una opcion con el codigo, solo que solo que el unico problema esta que al dar hover en el texto se hace un pequeño glitch por haber usado el selector y que el texto este arriba de la imagen misma

```css
.image {
    float: left;
    width: 28%; 
    margin: 10px
    z-index:2;
}

.image iframe{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

.desvanecer{
  max-width: 300px;
}

.image p{
font-family:arial;
color:#000;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
bottom:60px;
left:50px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
z-index:2;
display:inline-block;
visibility:hidden;
}

.desvanecer:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -ms-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.image img:hover ~ p{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"> 
     <img class="desvanecer" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" title="Texto encima">
     <p>Texto</p>
     <iframe src="https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/es/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```